# Rails: where does the @controller come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on an old plugin "menu_helper" (legacy code uses it).

https://github.com/pluginaweek/menu_helper

The main entrance of this library is as follows,

```
module PluginAWeek
  module MenuHelper
    def menu_bar(options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
      puts @controller.class
      MenuBar.new(@controller, options, html_options, &block).html
    end
  end
end

ActionController::Base.class_eval do
  helper PluginAWeek::MenuHelper
end
```

The code works in rails 2.3.5 without problem but fails in 4.2.6.

When I puts @controller.class, in 2.3.5, it will always return the current controller that is using this library, but in 4.2.6 it will be NillClass.

So where does this @controller come from? How do I modify in 4.2.6 to make it work.

Note 1: to use this, I just need to call

```
html = menu_bar(options,:id => 'menuid')
```

No any controller is passed in.

Note 2: I am currently running it on controller test.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of the gem `menu_helper` are you at in your `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: @born4new The latest version I can find is 0.3.1 which is pretty old. The old 2.3.5 rails was using 0.1.0, and in 4.2.6 I tried 0.1.0 and 0.3.1 they both failed at the same place. the (at)controller is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would not use a gem that has not been maintained in the past 5 years and that the master build is currently failing. I'd try to find a well-maintained alternative or if the gem is small enough, to redo it myself.

This being said, `menu_helper` seems to use this variable: https://github.com/pluginaweek/menu_helper/blob/master/lib/menu_helper/menu.rb#L51

If you want to make it work, do a `before_action` that would instantiate this variable with the current controller:

```
before_action :set_legacy_controller

def set_legacy_controller
  @controller = controller
end
```

Comment: thanks. I changed (at)controller to controller, it works now. So in old rails, you use (at)controller to refer to the current controller, in newer version of rails, you use controller, is it?  I tried to puts (at)controller in ApplicationHelper.rb, works in old rails 2.3, but not working in 4.2. But directly puts controller.class will work in 4.2.

Comment: To be honest, I never worked with Rails 2, but yeah I suppose it was `@controller` beforehand.

Comment: Thanks. I know using old gems is not good, but the boss requires to migrate from legacy. Or probably I can just directly print out those menu html without using the menu_helper gem, maybe even faster than migrating the library itself, lolz.

Comment: Definitely! And if you look at code of the gem, there's not too much to write 